# Applescript System Events Returns .DS_Store - How can I ignore

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion

I have looked around on the net for hours looking for this answer so I apologize if its there somewhere.  This script below works fine except for the fact that it returns the .DS_Store file how can I exclude it from this query and all other hidden files for that matter but because I am creating the folder in my script the only one there is .DS_Store

**tell application "System Events"
        set listOfInputs to POSIX path of every disk item of folder a as list
    end tell**

Here is the full script below.  I have been dropping files into the in folder after it is created but will eventually prompt for files before it is created.

on run

```
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists folder "IN") then
        make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"IN"}
    end if
    if not (exists folder "OUT") then
        make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"OUT"}
    end if
end tell


set theINfolder to path to the desktop as string
set a to theINfolder & "IN:"


tell application "System Events"
    set listOfInputs to POSIX path of every disk item of folder a as list
end tell

set inputs to listOfInputs

set theOutfolder to path to the desktop as string
set outputFolder to theOutfolder & "OUT:"

set params to {}

main(inputs, outputFolder, params)
```

end run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The List Folder command has been deprecated and may stop working unexpectedly.

Try:

```
set inFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "IN"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (POSIX path of inFolder)
set listOfInputs to paragraphs 2 thru -1 of (do shell script ("find " & quoted form of (POSIX path of inFolder) & " \\! -name \".*\""))
```

You can get the result as a string separated by spaces like this:

```
set inFolder to (path to desktop as text) & "IN"
do shell script "mkdir -p " & quoted form of (POSIX path of inFolder)
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, " "}
set listOfInputs to paragraphs 2 thru -1 of (do shell script ("find " & quoted form of (POSIX path of inFolder) & " \\! -name \".*\"")) as text
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Comment: Thanks also.  I did not realize that List Folder had been deprecated doing shell script was the route I tried first with no luck.  I doubt shell script will be deprecated any time soon. do you know how I can return a string (not in a list but separated by spaces?) of list of inputs to use in a separate shell script I am working on?

Comment: Thanks a tonne....this site is great. Quick and efficient. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
set listOfInputs to list folder a without invisibles
```

But `without invisibles` cannot be combined with `POSIX path`, so we use a loop instead:

```
set listOfInputs to {}
tell application "System Events"
    set the_items to list folder a without invisibles
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of the_items
        set this_item to alias ((a as Unicode text) & (item i of the_items))
        set end of listOfInputs to POSIX path of this_item
    end repeat
end tell
```